# Power BI Vega-Lite userdefinded format for Tooltip from data-column

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I have a simple bar-chart. The data for this barchart are provided by a measure. To this measure an other measure will provide a corresponding formatstring ig ".0%"

Depending on Userselection different formats will be used.
In this simplified example the format, provided in the column myFormat, will be percent (".0%")

The formating for the axis, using the col. myformat, is working.

The tooltip, currently only showing decimal num, should also be formated by the field myformat. Thus the format should not be static, but using the format from the col. myformat.

```
`{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 0.1, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 0.3, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "C", "b": 0.2, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "D", "b": 0.1, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "E", "b": 0.4, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "F", "b": 0.9, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "G", "b": 0.2, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "H", "b": 0.7, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "I", "b": 0.7, "myformat": ".0%"}
    ]
  },
  "mark":  {"type": "bar","tooltip": true}, 
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"labelExpr": "format(datum.label,data('source_0')[0]['myformat'])"}
    }
  }
}`
```

How to show the formated values in the tooltip (axis und tooltip should have the same format, provided by then field myformat, since the format in this column can change)?

Comment: Is this for Power BI?

Comment: yes it is for PowerBI. For the format the value of the field myformat should be used (because the measure which provides the format can contain different formats)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can use a data value to format the axis labels, but you can for the tooltip by doing the formatting in a calculate transform the using the new field in the tooltip.

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      { "a": "A", "b": 0.1, "myformat": ".0%" },
      { "a": "B", "b": 0.333333, "myformat": ".2f" },
      { "a": "C", "b": 0.2, "myformat": ".1%" },
      { "a": "D", "b": 0.1, "myformat": ".2%" },
      { "a": "E", "b": 0.4, "myformat": ".1f" },
      { "a": "F", "b": 0.9, "myformat": ".2f" },
      { "a": "G", "b": 0.2, "myformat": ".3f" },
      { "a": "H", "b": 0.7, "myformat": ".4f" },
      { "a": "I", "b": 0.7, "myformat": ".5f" }
    ]
  },
  "mark": { "type": "bar", "tooltip": true },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "format( datum['b'], datum['myformat'])",
      "as": "_formattted_tooltip"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "a",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {
        "labelExpr": "format(datum.label, '.0%')"
      }
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {
        "field": "_formattted_tooltip",
        "type": "nominal",
        "title": "b"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```